# Can I force the use of my dependencies' Cargo.lock when resolving package versions?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

The [Cargo FAQ states](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/faq.html#why-do-binaries-have-cargolock-in-version-control-but-not-libraries) that `Cargo.lock` is not used for libraries, instead using dependency version ranges found in `Cargo.toml`, to reduce lib duplication among shared dependencies.

However, I think there are instances where using a known successful build of a lib dependency is preferable. Namely, when a dependency no longer builds due to updates of its *own* dependencies.

Is it possible to configure Cargo to favour a library's `Cargo.lock`, over `Cargo.toml`, if it's available? Preferably on a by-package basis.

---

(**Update**: the issue below has been fixed in wither 0.5.1, where the dependency is now `mongodb = "0.10.*"`. However, it seems that this issue would re-appear if mongodb updates its bson dependency - at least until wither's dependencies are updated once again to match. Or, as @Shepmaster mentions in his answer, until [RFC 1977](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1977-public-private-dependencies.md) is implemented.)

My particular situation is trying to use the package [wither 0.5.0](https://docs.rs/wither/0.5.0/wither/index.html):

- wither's `Cargo.toml` specifies dependencies `mongodb = "<1.0"` and `bson = "<1.0"`
- mongodb's `Cargo.toml` specifies `bson = "0.10.0"`
- bson's latest version is at `0.11.1`

Without configuring dependencies further, `bson 0.10.0` is used for mongodb, and `bson 0.11.1` is used for wither. This causes compilation of wither to fail, as it uses some structures from bson to interact with mongodb.

My current workaround is a locally-cloned copy of wither, with an edited `Cargo.toml` to fix its version of bson. However, the [git repository](https://github.com/thedodd/wither) includes a committed `Cargo.lock`, which would allow me at least to use this repository as my dependency target, rather than cloning and modifying the package myself.

Comment: *Or simply because semantic versioning often cannot be relied upon - a symptom of the chronic issue of pre-1.0.0 packages in Rust.* These two statements are not related to each other. If you don't believe in semantic versioning or humans ability to follow it, then the fact that a crate is pre- or post-1.0 will have no bearing whatsoever.

Comment: Sure - pre-1.0.0, packages are explicitly volatile. However, this means that 90% of the packages in my Cargo.lock can/should not be automatically updated. Perhaps I should've said "...because semantic versioning guarantees are often unavailable".

Comment: Actually, semver as followed by Cargo provides versioning guarantees for pre-1.0 versions just fine.  If the major version is 0, then changing the minor version is considered breaking.  If that's also 0, then changing the revision number is considered breaking.  Pre-1.0 semver is just regular semver with the digits shifted over.

Comment: @DK thanks for pointing that out. It even alludes to this in [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-version-field) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot use a library's Cargo.lock.

> as it uses some structures from bson to interact with mongodb.

This is the root problem. Currently, it's unknown to the dependency resolver that one crate has exposed another crate's types in a public interface. That will be addressed when [RFC 1977](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1977-public-private-dependencies.md) is implemented.

As described in [Consolidating cargo dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38574874/155423), you can nudge the version of the dependency to be consolidated:

```
cargo update -p bson:0.11.1 --precise 0.10.0
```

See also:

- [Consolidating cargo dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38574874/155423)
- [Set specific version of the dependency of a project's dependency in Cargo.toml or Cargo.lock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27770031/155423)

---

That being said, *because* of semver, your code works just fine:

```
[dependencies]
wither = "0.5.1"
mongodb = "0.3.7"
```

```
$ cargo tree --invert -p bson
bson v0.10.0
├── mongodb v0.3.7
│   ├── example v0.1.0 (file:///private/tmp/example)
│   └── wither v0.5.1
│       └── example v0.1.0 (file:///private/tmp/example) (*)
```

> Seemingly unavoidably, bson 0.10.0 is used for mongodb, and bson 0.11.1 is used for wither.

This is not the case, as you can tell by (a) the example above and (b) your own statements about the acceptable version ranges.

Comment: Thanks - I was unaware of `--precise.`. Re: the code working just fine, version 0.5.0 was broken, and 0.5.1 was released about an hour after I posted this question!