# How to destructure an enum from a transitive dependency?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

src/main.rs:

```rust
fn main() {}

fn test(fetch: imap::types::Fetch) {
    // Variable of type &BodyStructure
    let bodystructure = fetch.bodystructure().unwrap();

    match bodystructure {
        imap_proto::BodyStructure::Basic { .. } => {}
        imap_proto::BodyStructure::Message { .. } => {}
        imap_proto::BodyStructure::Multipart { .. } => {}
        imap_proto::BodyStructure::Text { .. } => {}
    };
}
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "stackoverflow-68445809"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
imap = "2.4.1"

# This dependency solves the problem
# imap-proto = "0.10.2"
```

The code does not compile:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `imap_proto`
 --> src/main.rs:8:9
  |
8 |         imap_proto::BodyStructure::Basic { .. } => {}
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `imap_proto`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `imap_proto`
 --> src/main.rs:9:9
  |
9 |         imap_proto::BodyStructure::Message { .. } => {}
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `imap_proto`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `imap_proto`
  --> src/main.rs:10:9
   |
10 |         imap_proto::BodyStructure::Multipart { .. } => {}
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `imap_proto`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `imap_proto`
  --> src/main.rs:11:9
   |
11 |         imap_proto::BodyStructure::Text { .. } => {}
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `imap_proto`
```

`imap-proto` is a dependency of the `imap` crate and the code compiles after adding the dependency `imap-proto = "0.10.2"` to my project.

Is there a method to destructure variable `bodystructure` without explicitly depending on `imap-proto` crate? The requirement to add additional dependencies only to destructure variable seems weird to me. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Can I force the use of my dependencies' Cargo.lock when resolving package versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49723779/155423); [Consolidating cargo dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38574874/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thank you for your advice. I edited my question and added a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my reading of the documentation for the imap crate, the bodystructure function returns an Option<&BodyStructure<'a>>, where BodyStructure is an enum that's defined in the imap-proto crate. So I think that the answer is no, you'll have to include imap-proto as a dependency in addition to imap.

Source: https://docs.rs/imap/2.4.1/imap/types/struct.Fetch.html#method.bodystructure