# unknown feature `llvm_asm` when compile rust-src

Tags: rust

I tried to compile rust-src using cargo xbuild but get this error:

```
error[E0635]: unknown feature `llvm_asm`
-> .cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/compiler_builtins-0.1.28/src/lib.rs:3:12
3 | #![feature(llvm_asm)]
```

How can I fix this error? It's seem like xbuild tries to compile the new rust-src with an old rustc. I want it to also use the old rust-src.

I can't update to a newer rustc version as it results in lots of "R_x86_32 relocation" errors, so I would prefer to use the 2020-03-24 version.

#### Minimal example

**command**

```
cargo new --bin test

rustup component add rust-src

cargo install cargo-xbuild

cd test

ls test
Cargo.toml  rust-toolchain  src  x86_64-unknown-none.json
```

**rust-toolchain**

```
nightly-2020-03-24
```

**x86_64-unknown-none.json**

```
{
  "llvm-target": "x86_64-unknown-none",
  "data-layout": "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128",
  "arch": "x86_64",
  "target-endian": "little",
  "target-pointer-width": "64",
  "target-c-int-width": "32",
  "os": "none",
  "executables": true,
  "linker-flavor": "ld.lld",
  "linker": "rust-lld",
  "panic-strategy": "abort",
  "disable-redzone": true,
  "features": "-mmx,-sse,+soft-float"
}
```

**src/main.rs**

```
#![no_std]                // don't link the Rust standard library
#![no_main]               // disable all Rust-level entry points
#![allow(non_snake_case)] // disable non snake case name warning

use core::panic::PanicInfo;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn _start() -> ! {
    loop {}
}

#[panic_handler]
pub fn MyPacnicHandler(_panicInfo: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
    loop {}
}
```

**compile**

```
cargo xbuild --target x86_64-unknown-none
```

**rustc --version**

```
rustc 1.44.0-nightly (1edd389cc 2020-03-23)
```

Comment: You cannot compile new nightly code with an old nightly compiler — there's no stability guarantees for nightly builds. You need to use new code and a new compiler or old code and an old compiler. You've already eliminated one of those possibilities, leaving you with only the other.

Comment: how can i use old code then? should i download old code from github and copy it to specific folder?

Comment: [How to specify the exact version of a dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45224563/155423); [Set specific version of the dependency of a project's dependency in Cargo.toml or Cargo.lock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27770031/155423)

Comment: in my case, it a component called 'rust-src', not some crate or dependency.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in [cargo-xbuild](https://github.com/rust-osdev/cargo-xbuild). Basically, `cargo xbuild` unconditionally fetches the latest `compiler_builtins`.

A patch has been merged, but is not yet in the latest `crates.io` release. See this PR: https://github.com/rust-osdev/cargo-xbuild/pull/75/commits/eede1a1d4c08064763f1943c0920de2270260b33

Comment: Yeah, it's indeed a bug in xbuild. New xbuild work perfect!

Comment: The command linked in that issue almost works, though the mentioned branch no longer exists.  `master` worked for me: `cargo install cargo-xbuild --git https://github.com/rust-osdev/cargo-xbuild.git --branch master  --debug --force`

Comment: Note that this change has now been pulled into `cargo xbuild` version `0.5.32`. Unfortunately, that version also causes xbuild to use the `embed-bitcode` option to `rustc`, which was introduced in late March 2020. If you are using an older `rustc` version, you will need to build `cargo xbuild` from source using this commit: https://github.com/rust-osdev/cargo-xbuild/commit/cf1128abaaa61a6f73d1276d30bbda530a188e76

Answer (score -1):

Update your rust version by `rustup update`, which works for me.

The reason may be the feature rename in new version : https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/71007

Comment: From the OP: *Note: I can't update to newer rustc version*

Comment: @Shepmaster Sorry for not reading your comments, you are right. The answer is not suitable here but maybe someone else can see it.